# Запуск .dll файла на определенное время

Tags: c#, asp

не подскажете возможно ли на `c# asp net core/framework` запустить `.dll` файл?

Но важно то, чтобы процесс был управляемым, и через определенное время автоматический крашил процесс(если файл не завершил выполнение за определенное время).

Варианты типо:

```cs
Process.Start();
```

Даже можно не предлогать, так как это запуск файла, он он будет НЕ управляемым, а мне нужно чтобы был управляемым.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что вы произвольную dll сможете запустить с контролем тайм-аута. Так что если это чужая библиотека, то я бы сказал - "никак не запустить". А если это ваша - то перефразируйте вопрос "как написать такую библиотеку чтобы и нужно больше подробностей что и как вы пишете в этой dll.

Comment: Dll бывают разные, можете более конкретно рассказать, что вы хотите делать с библиотекой?

Comment: По факту .dll компилирую через CSharpCodeProvider(стандартные возможности c#)

Comment: Насчет внутреннего кода .dll, суть в том что это не библиотека, а просто кучу программ, которые запускпются на сервере

Comment: Не обьязательно .dll, можно .exe

Comment: Процесс вполне можно убить: [Process.Kill method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Вы пишете, что сами компилируете. Значит у вас есть доступ к исходникам. Добавьте туда входной параметр `CancellationToken` и используйте его в коде.

Comment: Что-то я пока не пойму куда добавить ```CancellationToken```. Учитывайте, что все делаю на ```c# asp.net framework/core```, и эти запуски делаю в фоновом процессе.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы подразумеваете под "процесс не будет управляемым". Запустите ```Process p = Process.Start(...);``` добавьте какой-то ```Timer``` и в обработчике события таймера сделайте ```p.Kill();```. Или что не так в этом примере?

Comment: Похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567)

Comment: Как пользоваться c# я знаю, и такие основы как Process.kill я знаю, я задал вопрос куда писать CancellationToken! Так как вариант с Token мне подходиь больше. У меня дело в том что у меня это все еще и происходит в класс который наследует IHostedServices. И я перезапускаю класс каждые 5 секунд

Comment: Давайте я тогда более подробно распищу.

Comment: Да, распишите подробней. Вы отвергаете запуск и убийство процесса, также вы отвергли загрузку и выгрузку сборок. Могу предложить третий вариант: плагинную систему: [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/). Можно и без стороннего фреймворка определить интерфейс и на его основе создавать и загружать код.